# Selenium Webdriver JUNIT Maven Eclipse Running Test Cases fails

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run test cases using JUNIT 4.10 with Selenium for a Web Application using Maven in Eclipse.

I have created a simple java project with JUNIT Test cases added proper dependency.
It works perfectly fine with `Run as a JUNIT Test case` but it does not work as Maven Test so something like `mvn clean test` is not working.

Here is my excerpt of pom.xml

```
    <build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.10</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
  <version>3.8</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

also here is my JUnit Test case which I wrote,

```
@Test()
public void testTC101() throws InterruptedException{
    driver.get(ADMIN_BASE_URL_QA);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(12, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='top30Events']"));
    WebElement loanModFullEvent = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText(QA_MOD_FULL_EVENT));
    loanModFullEvent.click();
    String clickedFullEventId = loanModFullEvent.findElement(By.xpath("..")).getAttribute("id").split("_")[1];
    List<WebElement> nearbyEvents = driver.findElements(By.id("nearby_events_" + clickedFullEventId));
    ListIterator<WebElement> wIterator = nearbyEvents.listIterator();
    WebElement element = null;
    String registerNowId = null;
    while(wIterator.hasNext()) {
        element = wIterator.next().findElement(By.linkText(QA_MOD_NONFULL_EVENT));
        element.click();
        registerNowId = element.getAttribute("onclick").replaceAll("\\D+", "");
    }
    registerNowId = "top30_" + registerNowId;
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='" + registerNowId + "']/div[3]/div/a")).click();              
    WebElement dropDownListBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='list']"));
    Select clickThis = new Select(dropDownListBox);
    clickThis.selectByValue("mod");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='situationdropdown']/div/div/div[1]/span/span/span/input")).click();
    RegistrationForm.fillFormAndSubmit();

}
```

Code is just for the idea, but the problem is It is running in JUnit Test case why not using maven. It says tests : 0 runs : 0 skips : 0

Why it is not recognizing the tests, I am still not sure why? Can someone help?

Comment: Have you put the test class in src/test/java directory? And furthermore, what is the name of the test class? It must either end with Test or start with it.

Comment: It does conform to both the things. it ends with "Tests"

Comment: any resources that you can guide to also would be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that your test class name ends with Tests. That is not one of the default patterns according to the surefire plugin site: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

```
**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that start with "Test
**/*Test.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "Test
**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "TestCase
```

Comment: you are on target. It just solved my issue. man I saw that link but did not realize this sorry for the post.

Comment: There's nothing to be sorry for.  Happy coding!